# Migration from C++ Visual 2006 to V2010 CFile to ifstream

Tags: c++, c++11, migration

I would like to migrate some piece of code written in C++ Visual 2006 do C++ V2010.
It was:

```
CFile *fInp;
...
int iStatus = fInp->Read(chMsg, iMaxBuffer);
```

and now I am trying to do this like:

```
ifstream *fInp;
...
int iStatus = fInp->read(chMsg, iMaxBuffer);
```

but CFile::Read returns int with value of how many characters has been moved, but ifstream::read doesn't.
How can I get that value?

Will this work:

```
fInp->read(chMsg, iMaxBuffer);
int iStatus = fInp->gcount();
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/), my answer would be the following :

```
ifstream *fInp;
//...
fInp->read(buffer, iMaxBuffer);

if (*fInp)
    std::cout << "read " << iMaxBuffer << " characters successfully.";
else
    std::cout << "only " << fInp->gcount() << " could be read";
```

Comment: gcount() will not just return same value as iMaxBuffer if all of them will be read?

Comment: I suppose it will, but please test it on your side before assuming anythnig !

Answer (score 0):

CFile and ifstream aren't really related at all, not sure why you're trying to replace CFile with an ifstream.

Is there a reason why you can't use CFile?  It should still work with later versions of VS.

EDIT:

In addition to VB_overflow's answer, I guess you could do something like this if you feel like you really need an iStatus variable rather than just checking fInp with an if.

```
int iStatus = fInp->failbit;
```

If it is true, it means it hasn't failed.  I think I prefer just doing an if(fInp) though.

Comment: OP does not want to output iMaxBuffer value to the console ... he wants to know how much characters have been read ...

Comment: I just want to use std library :) Thanks anyway

Comment: I've edited my answer regarding your iStatus bit.  I like VB_overflow's though.

Comment: By the way CFile works only in VS2010 Professional. Probably this will be solution for my migration, because CFile and fstream methods does not work the same way.